# What's this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, identification

What does the bottom symbol mean on this capacitor?  (the "U<" marking)

[image: curious capacitor]

Am I correct reading:

B    = +- 0.1% tolerance

222K = 222000pF or 222nF

1KV  = rated for 1000V

Was unable to find any 1KV's on mouser or digikey with that tolerance so am assuming I'm reading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what the B is.. maybe someone else knows. Similar letters appear on capacitors from various manufacturers so perhaps they are aping the markings of a well-known supplier.

222 is 2200 pF or 2.2nF.  22 for value followed by 2 zeroes.

K is the tolerance code (+/-10%) according to JIS

1kV is the voltage rating.

This value and voltage rating of capacitor is typically used in X or Y applications (across or from mains to ground), however properly certified products will have parts festooned with safety agency marks.

The bottom marking is probably a manufacturer's logo or initials of their name. There are many, many such manufacturers. I don't think it's directly relevant to the ratings.

Comment: Thanks!  Especially helpful to know the K is a tolerance code.

Comment: Of course, if the part is counterfeit, then whatever safety agency marks it has are likely fake as well.  Counterfeiters have a wide variety of skill, with some being professionally indistinguishable from the real thing...until it kills a product...or people.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I only mentioned it because you mentioned the marks.  As long as counterfeiting is a significant problem, no mark can be trusted on its own.  How good is your supply chain, and how well do you know that?

Comment: So what does that `U<` mean?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The bottom marking is probably a manufacturer's logo or initials of their name. There are many, many such manufacturers. I don't think it's directly relevant to the ratings.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that this is a varistor:

[image: varistor photo]

Photo source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Varistor_S14K385_photo.jpg

Michael Schmid, CC BY-SA 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/, via Wikimedia Commons

Comment: While they do look similar (there are technological reasons for this similarity), the markings on the element in the OP are consistent with capacitance and voltage rating.